# QSqlDatabase no error printed and no output?

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, qtsql, qsqldatabase

I use `QSqlDatabase` to insert data to mysql.

First, I define a class named `Inserter`:

```
class Inserter
{
    QSqlDatabase db_connection;
    
public:
    Insert()
    {
        db_connection = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");

        db_connection.setDatabaseName("dbname");

        db_connection.setHostName("localhost");

        db_connection.setUserName("root");

        db_connection.setPassword("psd");

        if(!db_connection.open())
        {
            qDebug() << db_connection.lastError();
        }
    }
};
```

And then, I use `Insert` in another class defined as Scheduler:

```
class Scheduler
{
    Inserter inserter;
public:
    Scheduler()
    {
        inserter = Inserter();
    }
};
```

When I run this program, Qt print warning:

> QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection 'qt_sql_default_connection' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
>
> QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name 'qt_sql_default_connection', old connection removed.

[someone said:](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/12759-Multiple-database-connections)

> QSqlDatabase::addDatabase() is supposed to be called once per type and connection name. Calling addDatabase("QMYSQL") multiple times leads to `QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name 'qt_sql_default_connection', old connection removed.`
>
> Furthermore, having existing QSqlQuery objects while removing a database leads to `QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection 'qt_sql_default_connection' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.`

If the above reason of the warning is right, why the sequence of the warning is not to be:

> QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name 'qt_sql_default_connection', old connection removed.
>
> QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection 'qt_sql_default_connection' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.

At last, I move the initial code to the class `Scheduler` as follow:

```
class Scheduler
{
    QSqlDatabase db_connection;
  
    void initDBConnection()
    {
        db_connection = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");

        db_connection.setDatabaseName("walmart");

        db_connection.setHostName("localhost");

        db_connection.setUserName("root");

        db_connection.setPassword("");
 
        if(!db_connection.open())
        {
            qDebug() << db_connection.lastError();
        }
    }

public:
    Scheduler()
    {
        initDBConnection();
    }
};
```

There is no warning or errors printed.

Comment: So, your question is about the reverse order? If so, you could update the title to reflect that.

Comment: @LaszloPapp my question is why Qt print that warning...